# Android app doesn't show up as a connected app despite verification and several days of waiting

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to connect my Android app to AoG brand verification to enable transactions.  3 Web sites are "connected" in Brand verification.  I went through the "Connect app" flow, selecting the application in play.google.com, and verified all 3 sites in Play console.  Then I waited for days.  Then I tried again and waited 3 more days.  Nothing.  The app is never connected.

The answer I got from support is try again.  Has anyone seen and solved this issue?  I know this is not much to go on, but it's not like you get any intel from play console or AoG console about what is actually happening behind the scenes.

Thanks,
socasanta

I tried the entire connect flow about 3 times now with a 3 day wait since the last go around.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, sharing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps other developers replicate your project's behavior, then give helpful advice. Do you have a Github repo with a copy of your project that other developers can review?

Comment: Have you managed get the apps connected? What solved it?

Comment: Hi Yigal, I was never able to get it to work and ended up going in a completely different direction.